# Dictionary entries: etw. zusammentragen vs zusammentragen

Tags: translation, dictionary

In dict.cc, *etw. zusammentragen* is translated as *to collect sth*, whereas *zusammentragen* is translated as *to collate*.

Why isn't the entry given as follows:

> **etw.** zusammentragen = collate **sth.**

This is just one of the thousands of similar situations. In some cases *etw.* in front of a verb is indeed inappropriate (e.g. *gedeihen* = *flourish*), but in the case of *zusammentragen* it just seems that compilers of the dictionary have been somewhat sloppy, merely failing to add *etw.* in front of the verb.

Is it proper that there's no *etw.* in front of *zusammentragen*, when it's translated as *collate*?

Comment: Stricktly speaking, "to collate" is wrong either. We would have to ask dict.cc why they also allow the versions without the object.

Comment: Isn’t this technically a question about how correct dict.cc is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*zusammentragen* has the following meaning:

> von verschiedenen Stellen herbeischaffen und zu einem bestimmten Zweck sammeln

(source: [Duden.de](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/zusammentragen))

**Translated into english:**

> collecting from different places for a specific purpose.

Collating includes collecting *and* combining information such as texts or data (regarding to [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/collate)). Thus the most appropriated translation is, indeed, to collect.

**There is *no* difference in the meaning von *zusammentragen* with or without the object. Using it without any object (without the *etw.*) is wrong**